# I would like to query MS teams download site for the latest version on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, microsoft-teams

I would like to query MS teams download site for the latest version on python, I am automating MS teams to one click "repair", it reinstalls itself whence my program is run.

However I am making use of a static link at the moment and would like to know is there a way to query for the latest version so that when my request runs I can have an argument to ask for the latest version instead of relying on a static link that will have to be updated manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
if os.path.exists("C:/Users/%s/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams" %Name): 
print("installed, please close teams and rerun this program.")
time.sleep(10)

else:
url = 'https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/production-windows-x64/1.4.00.19572/Teams_windows_x64.exe' 

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

total_size_in_bytes= int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))

block_size = 1024 

progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_size_in_bytes, unit='iB', unit_scale=True)

with open('c:/users/%s/downloads/Teams.exe' %Name, 'wb') as file:
    for data in response.iter_content(block_size):
        progress_bar.update(len(data))
        file.write(data)

progress_bar.close() 

if total_size_in_bytes != 0 and progress_bar.n != total_size_in_bytes:
    print("ERROR: Something went wrong, check connection and try again, or see help.txt for more info")
    time.sleep(10)
```

I might not have explained it properly, but the request function uses a static link, is there no way I can rather query the download site for the latest version, I basically just need to ask the site for the latest version of teams to reinstall otherwise ill have to manually update the link as teams updates.

This is the snippet of code that downloads and displays a progress bar where url = "static link" i want to get a way to insert the latest links automatically.

My script works it reinstalls teams and displays a progress bar no errors in the program itself just want to better it for universal use.

My last option is to use the update.exe file teams uses to get the latest version but I don't want it to depend on any .exes being locally present in the script folder rather just the code should do the job.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
I'm sorry for the backlash, but sadly I have to agree with the downvoter.
Your question is not specific enough to get answered here. Please post what you tried so far, what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Create a minimal reproducable example.

Your question of 'how to check for a new teams version' is not python-, jquery- or sql-related.

Comment: I'd say the right place to ask this question would probable be in the MS teams support forum, if something like that exists.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow, but it heavily depends on how exactly MS teams publishes its new versions. Which is not common knowledge (to me at least).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to https://teams.microsoft.com/desktopclient/installer/windows/x64 it will return the url of the most recent package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
os.system('cmd /k "winget install Microsoft.Teams"')
print("installed, Exiting in 10 seconds")
time.sleep(10)
```

Well i cut my code in half after finding out about winget and how to utilize it in python, solved my problem and i can now always download the latest teams with cmd feedback instead of using a static source and coding my own progress bar.